# Why doesn't Bumblebee work with NVidia GTX675M in Ubuntu 12.04.2

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I'm trying use my NVidia video card in Ubuntu 12.04.2 but without success. The model of my video card is GTX675M. I've installed Bumblebee using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates -y && sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable -y && sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
```

After the installation I restarted Ubuntu and tried to run:

```
hudson@hudson-avell:~$ optirun glxspheres
[ 8526.101459] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initialize the NVIDIA GPU at PCI:1:0:0.  Please

[ 8526.101532] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

My `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf` is this:

```
[bumblebeed]
VirtualDisplay=:8
KeepUnusedXServer=false
ServerGroup=bumblebee
TurnCardOffAtExit=false
NoEcoModeOverride=false
Driver=
XorgConfDir=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d

[optirun]
Bridge=auto
VGLTransport=proxy
PrimusLibraryPath=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
AllowFallbackToIGC=false

[driver-nvidia]
KernelDriver=nvidia-current
PMMethod=auto
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-current:/usr/lib32/nvidia-current
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-current/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia

[driver-nouveau]
KernelDriver=nouveau
PMMethod=auto
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nouveau
```

I did the following changes:

```
Driver=
[driver-nvidia]
KernelDriver=nvidia
Module=nvidia-current
```

But this time the message is saying that Bumblebee is not running. What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you added yourself to the `bumblebee` group? (`sudo usermod -a -G bumblebee <your_username>`, then restart)

Comment: I did it, but the result is the same